# How to insert all the dates in a date range into Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, insert, date

For instance, The date range is from 26th Jul to 1st Aug, that is

> 26th Jul, 27th Jul, 28th Jul, 29th Jul, 30th Jul, 31th Jul and 1st Aug

How can I construct a function (of course, I need to implement this function using SQL or PL/SQL) like this:

```
// insert all the dates from "from" to "to" ("from" and "to" are included)
// into Oracle datebase
bool InsertDateRange(date from, date to) {
    bool state = true;

    for (date d in [from, to]) {
        // insert
    }

    return state;
}
```

If given a different date range, say [27th Feb, 1st Mar], I also need to know this year is a leap year or a common year.

Comment: Do you need to insert dates, or do you need to write a function to insert dates? These are different things. Also, I don't recognize the language you're using -- it looks similar to Java, but data types are unfamiliar to me.  If you want a function, what language are you planning to use?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot describe this question clearly. I need SQL (maybe PL/SQL) to implement  this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query to generate a sequence of dates, something like this:

```
insert into my_table (my_date_column) 
select dt + (level - 1) 
from (select date '<your start date>' dt from dual)
connect by dt + (level - 1) <= date '<your end date plus 1 day>';
```

Date arithmetics: `dt + (level - 1)` -- are smart enough to know when one month ends and another begins (including Februaries in leap years).

If you do need a PL/SQL function for this, I'm sure you will be able to wrap it around this statement easily.